# Xamarin Resource.designer.cs not generating reference for newly add file

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am adding a file called citybase.png to my drawable folder when I set the src property of my ImageView to @drawable/citybase the image is not showing up in the design view. Inspecting the Resource.designer.cs class I realize that no reference is being generated for any files I add to the drawable folder(except for the default Icon of course).

```
    public partial class Drawable
    {

        // aapt resource value: 0x7f020000
        public const int Icon = 2130837504;

        static Drawable()
        {
            global::Android.Runtime.ResourceIdManager.UpdateIdValues();
        }

        private Drawable()
        {
        }
    }
```

I tried rebuilding and cleaning the project but that does not work. How can I fix this problem? (Xamarin Studio 4.2.3)

Comment: You shouldn't put images in `drawable` folder. Use dpi-specific folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The drawable folder name should be in lowercase (in visual studio it always create with name 'Drawable' when creating project), also avoid using such symbols like '@', '#' and so on.